# jq getting multiple fields from same query

Tags: linux, bash, csv, jq

I have a json of this type:

```
{
  "_index": "indexeer",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "3233233233",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "Bibtex": {
      "Article": {
        "AuthorList": [
          {
            "Affiliation": {
              "Affiliation": "Title content, Hematology and Hepatology Honorary Fellow, Honorary Member, American  Society. xxxyyy@hotmail.com."
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the `Affiliation` using `jq` like so:

```
jq -r '._source.Bibtex.Article.AuthorList[]? | .Affiliation.Affiliation | .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")]' results.json
```

It works great, and gives me excatly the affiliations I need.

However, I now need the `id` field aswell and produce a csv like so:

```
"3233233233", "Title content, Hematology and Hepatology Honorary Fellow, Honorary Member, American  Society"
```

I am able to get the ID seperately, easily like so:

```
jq -r '._id' results.json
```

but, how do I combine the two queries to produce a single output consisting of `id` and `affiliation`?

Essentially I want to combine the two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` to construct an array from your two elements and `@csv` to convert to CSV:

```
jq -r '[
  ._id,
  ._source.Bibtex.Article.AuthorList[]?.Affiliation.Affiliation[:rindex(" Electronic address:")]
] | @csv'
```

Output:

```
"3233233233","Title content, Hematology and Hepatology Honorary Fellow, Honorary Member, American  Society. xxxyyy@hotmail.com."
```

Multiple authors will be added as columns to your CSV.

---

It's worth nothing that jq allows you to concatenate multiple arrays into a single one. Concatenating streams produces the cartesian product, e.g. `[1]+[2]` produces `[1,2]` and `[1]+([2],[3])` will produce `[1,2][1,3]` (a stream comprising two arrays). You can leverage this fact to produce multiple output lines without capturing the id in a variable first:

```
[._id]
+ (._source.Bibtex.Article.AuthorList[]? | [ .Affiliation.Affiliation[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")] ])
| @csv
```

Comment: @JohnJ you might find the update to my answer helpful

Answer (score 1):

Save the `id` as a variable using `._id as $id`, then you can use `$id` where ever you like:

```
._id as $id | ._source.Bibtex.Article.AuthorList[].Affiliation.Affiliation | [ $id, .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")] ] | @csv
```

Output:

```
"3233233233","Title content, Hematology and Hepatology Honorary Fellow, Honorary Member, American  Society. xxxyyy@hotmail.com."
```

---

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/298G4GJ2Kng)